# bug on hover element css

Tags: css, opacity

I have a problem.
If you hover on the triangle, menu will be light transparent.
I do not know what is the reason

```
.item-icon:hover{
transform: scale(1.25);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
-moz-transform: scale(1.25);
z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Add your full code please.

Comment: what triangle? can you add more complete code?

Comment: Sorry, i update question

Comment: sorry  but i cant see any difference.screenshot?

Comment: auuuf man, never post username and password to your site...please remove those immediately if you want your server to live

Comment: Do you mean when you hover over triangle, top horizontal menu becomes semi transparent for like 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i do not see any opacity issue, but you could try:

```
.item-icon:hover{
    transform: scale(1.25);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
    z-index: 2;

    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `z-index:2;` from `.item-icon:hover` class,
and add `z-index: 999;` to `.item-icon` class like below:

```
.item-icon {
  width: 48%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

i hope it will help for you

Answer (score 0):

when you hover over triangle, your div's of class `item-icon` are getting another class `active`. It might be that you are handling this in jquery where you change color for elements that have class `active` which results in change of font color of menu.

Comment: No, you see, these triangles interact with the right menu.
If you try to hover on the menu to the right you will see the mutations both

Comment: yes i can see there is coresponding right menu entry and its color changes as you hover over different triangles. That is what you want. Why does top horizontal menu  change color...im so far unable to determine. I will test at home with various browsers, mabye that leads me somewhere closer to give you an answer.